# Custom command with option

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, shortcuts

I'm using "ls -l" a lot is there a way say define a shortcut for that so i could call it "ll"? This way I can go and use short instead? Any pointers appreciated. Thanks. Michael

Comment: Many distributions already have ll set as an alias in the way pointed out by user221185.

Answer (score 7):

You can make an alias of "ls -l" like this:
alias ll="ls -l"

To make it permanent, you can add the above alias to the file ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three ways:

1. `echo 'alias ll="ls -l"'  >> ~/.bash_proflie`
2. `echo 'function ll { ls -l $@ ;}' >> ~/.bash_profile`
3. `echo ls -l > /usr/local/bin/ll   ; chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ll`

Don't forget to read the profile with `source ~/.bash_profile`.